# Failed to update and now causes module errors

Tags: 8, webforms, updating

I recently attempted to update a Drupal 8 site from 8.7.7 to 8.9.3 and had a failure due to server not being on the right version of php7 to run the new 8.9 version.

As a result I am now getting issues within /admin/people view with the following errors

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException</em>: The &quot;webform_submission_delete_action&quot; plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Action\ActionManager are: comment_delete_action, comment_unpublish_by_keyword_action, comment_publish_action, comment_save_action, comment_unpublish_action, node_promote_action, node_delete_action, node_make_unsticky_action, node_assign_owner_action, node_unpromote_action, node_make_sticky_action, node_save_action, node_publish_action, node_unpublish_action, node_unpublish_by_keyword_action, user_remove_role_action, user_unblock_user_action, user_cancel_user_action, user_block_user_action, user_add_role_action, pathauto_update_alias, entity:delete_action:comment, entity:delete_action:media, entity:delete_action:node, entity:publish_action:block_content, entity:publish_action:comment, entity:publish_action:media, entity:publish_action:node, entity:publish_action:taxonomy_term, entity:publish_action:menu_link_content, entity:publish_action:paragraph, action_message_action, entity:unpublish_action:block_content, entity:unpublish_action:comment, entity:unpublish_action:media, entity:unpublish_action:node, entity:unpublish_action:taxonomy_term, entity:unpublish_action:menu_link_content, entity:unpublish_action:paragraph, action_send_email_action, entity:save_action:block_content, entity:save_action:comment, entity:save_action:file, entity:save_action:media, entity:save_action:node, entity:save_action:taxonomy_term, entity:save_action:user, entity:save_action:font, entity:save_action:menu_link_content, action_goto_action in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;doGetDefinition()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">53</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php</em>).
```

The webform version went from 8.5.4 to 8.5.19

Within my modules admin, currently webform is showing as uninstalled. When I try to re-enable with drush I get a similar error.

```
php ../drush.phar pm-enable webform

In PreExistingConfigException.php line 65:
                                                                                                                                                                   
  Configuration objects (system.action.webform_submission_delete_action, system.action.webform_submission_make_lock_action, system.action.webform_submission_make  
  _sticky_action, system.action.webform_submission_make_unlock_action, system.action.webform_submission_make_unsticky_action, webform.settings, webform.webform.c  
  ontact, webform.webform_options.country_codes, webform.webform_options.country_names, webform.webform_options.days, webform.webform_options.education, webform.  
  webform_options.employment_status, webform.webform_options.ethnicity, webform.webform_options.gender, webform.webform_options.industry, webform.webform_options  
  .languages, webform.webform_options.likert_agreement, webform.webform_options.likert_comparison, webform.webform_options.likert_importance, webform.webform_opt  
  ions.likert_quality, webform.webform_options.likert_satisfaction, webform.webform_options.likert_ten_scale, webform.webform_options.likert_would_you, webform.w  
  ebform_options.marital_status, webform.webform_options.months, webform.webform_options.phone_types, webform.webform_options.relationship, webform.webform_optio  
  ns.size, webform.webform_options.state_codes, webform.webform_options.state_names, webform.webform_options.state_province_codes, webform.webform_options.state_  
  province_names, webform.webform_options.time_zones, webform.webform_options.titles, webform.webform_options.yes_no) provided by webform already exist in active  
   configuration
```

Has anyone encountered similar and can point me to how to get webform enabled again and to get rid of the errors?

Comment: It seems like the webform module was not fully uninstalled and there is leftover configuration in the database.

Comment: there was an issue with the version of the module not supporting the current the upgraded version of Drupal. I rolled back the version of Drupal, updated webform and then reapplied the drupal update.

Answer (score 1):

**What seems to the problem**

It seems during the failed update Webform was marked as uninstalled but its configuration objects are still present. This is preventing Webform to be enabled again because you can't install an extension that uses configuration objects already in the system.

**How to solve it**

You can remove all the configuration objects and try to install/enable the module. To remove them, you can use the [`cdel` drush command](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/config/config:delete/).

Given the configuration object list, the commands to run would be:

```
drush cdel system.action.webform_submission_delete_action  
drush cdel system.action.webform_submission_make_lock_action  
drush cdel system.action.webform_submission_make_sticky_action  
drush cdel system.action.webform_submission_make_unlock_action  
drush cdel system.action.webform_submission_make_unsticky_action  
drush cdel webform.settings  
drush cdel webform.webform.contact  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.country_codes  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.country_names  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.days  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.education  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.employment_status  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.ethnicity  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.gender  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.industry  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.languages  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.likert_agreement  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.likert_comparison  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.likert_importance  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.likert_quality  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.likert_satisfaction  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.likert_ten_scale  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.likert_would_you  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.marital_status  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.months  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.phone_types  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.relationship  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.size  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.state_codes  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.state_names  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.state_province_codes  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.state_province_names  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.time_zones  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.titles  
drush cdel webform.webform_options.yes_no
```

**Consecuences**

Removing configuration objects mean you likely are going to lose any Webform configuration you made. This can be not a problem if you can easily redo the configuration or your configuration was not finished or needed changes. I'm not sure if this includes losing all the created webforms.

However, if you dumped the configuration to files (using Drupal configuration system) you may able to recover the configuration using those files.